# My proof that $f[f^{-1}(D)] \subseteq D.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I've just started studying formal proof and set theory, so it'll be really cool if someone can check out my proof for a pretty basic set theory problem. It'll be great if you can tell me if my proof is correct and other tips to making it better. So here it goes:

**Theorem:**
Suppose that $f: A \rightarrow B$. Let $D$ be a subset of $B$. Prove that $$f[f^{-1}(D)] \subseteq D.$$
**Proof:**
Let $y \in f[f^{-1}(D)].$ Then, there exists an $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. Hence, $x \in f^{-1}(D)$, or in other terms, $x \in \{a \in A: f(a) \in D\}.$ Therefore, $f(x) \in D$ and since $f(x) = y, y \in D$. As a result, $f[f^{-1}(D)] \subseteq D.$

Comment: It is clearer to say directly that $y\in f[f^{-1}(D)]$ means there is a $x\in f^{-1}(D)$ with $f(x)=y$, but otherwise yes this is correct.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is correct, and I see nothing inconsistent with your proof.

I would choose to write it slightly more explicitly, but this is the same reasoning structured differently. Notice that the set $f[f^{-1}(D)]$ is by definition
$$f[f^{-1}(D)]=\{y\in B: \exists x\in f^{-1}(D)\;f(x)=y \}.$$
So if you select any particular $y_0\in f[f^{-1}(D)]$, we get some particular $x_0\in f^{-1}(D)$ with $f(x_0)=y_0$; similarly, $x_0\in f^{-1}(D)$ means (by definition) that there is some $d_0\in D$ such that $f(x_0)=d_0$. Then, by the defining property of functions,
$$y_0=f(x_0)=d_0,$$
and $d_0\in D$, as required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this reasoning is valid. Great job! However, you can make this more consise.

> Let $y \in f[f^{-1}(D)].$ Then, there exists an $x \in f^{-1}(D)$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $f^{-1}(D)=\{a \in A: f(a) \in D\}$, we must have $f(x) \in D$, but since $y=f(x)$, we get $y \in D$, concluding the proof.